# Use cases for DACPAC

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

The SQL Server DACPAC is a schema only version of a database.
My understanding is that this makes it easier to deploy databases.

In my experience however, a database, even without transnational data is rarely empty, there is always reference data, without which the database does not function.

I find that, due to the inability to store data, I have  very few use cases for a DACPAC and so I generally use a .bak or BACPAC.

Is there a larger use case for DATPAC files that i am not noticing?

Answer (score 3):

The DACPAC just another tool. Some people may want to only, ever, deploy schema. The DACPAC makes that possible. Situationally you may never use it, but others may. What if you're only deploying stored procedure changes? No need for a BACPAC, the DACPAC will fulfill that need. It's just about working within the requirements. You never have to use a DACPAC if it doesn't work for you, but the same applies to the BACPAC or any other mechanism within SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

Dacpac files can contain data in the same way that bacpac files do.  To get all table data, you can use:

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true
```

To get table data for specific tables, you can use:

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:extract /p:TableData=dbo.table1 /p:TableData=dbo.table2
```

Finally, dacpac files support post-deploy scripts, which can contain merge statements.  So you can turn your reference data into merge statements and place them into the post-deploy script.

Comment: I using DACPAC approach for my automatic database deployment on Azure Sql Server, now problem is that dacpac file is created in CI pipeline and going to release it on Azure SQL database using 'Azure SQL DacpacTask' but their I am facing another issue while publishing the dacpac File azure * Could not deploy package. Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ddltrg_CREATE_Activity_LOG, Line 16 Reference to database and/or server name in 'TrackDBChanges..tblDDLEventLog' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.". What I am doing wrong here